# How to setup routes for simple frontend routing

Tags: codeigniter

i'm a newbie in codeigniter.

I want to create a new page for the frontend - mynewpage.php.
The index.php in frontend will work fine.

So i do the following steps

In the Frontend.php Controller i add this

```
public function mynewpage()
    {
        $this->view = 'frontend/mynewpage';
        $this->layout();
    }
```

the mynewpage.php is still inside the "views/frontend/" folder

In the routes.php is this part for the frontend i think

```
$route['/']  = "frontend/";
$route['/(:any)']  = "frontend/$1";
```

This is inside my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

So if i enter my webadress like

```
-> www.example.com the index.php will be display and the adressfield show www.example.com
-> if i try www.example.com/mynewpage.php i get Error 404 - Page not found
-> if i try www.example.com/mynewpage i get Error 404 - Page not found
-> if i try www.example.com/frontend/mynewpage.php i get Error 404 - Page not found
-> if i try www.example.com/frontend/mynewpage the page will be show
```

**What i have to change or do that the mynewpage.php will be show on enter the adress without the "/fontend/" = www.exapmle.com/mynewpage and as mynewpage.php?**

Thanks a lot

Comment: For starters you do not put .php on the end of the URL. It's a controller/method arrangement as your last URL example demonstrates. If you are going to show functions like $this->layout() it would be helpful to show the code for that just for completeness.

Comment: Are they the only the only two routes you have?

Comment: how i can remove the "frontend" part in the shown url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a route for your `mynewpage`, something like:

`$route['mynewpage']  = "frontend/mynewpage";`

right now you have a route for frontend, but frontend is your controller. No need to route that.

see more about [CI URI Routing](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: it wont work - if i add this routingrule and enter the domain.com/mynewpage i get a error 404!?

Comment: change in Frontend controller function mynewpage(): `$this->load->view('mynewpage')`